# Should the port-80 tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tag-burnination

So I just came across [port-80](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port-80), and... I'm perplexed.  I don't see any purpose it serves.  However, before I launch it into the sun, does anyone want to speak up in its defence?

(I'm assuming that the [port-443](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port-443) tag will also be covered by this)

Comment: A note, If the community dont like my suggestion for the port tag, I suggest to burn it too, as I don't see the use to keep the port tag up, while burning others. (port-80, etc..)

Comment: [tag:port] is a much broader problem than the protocol-specific port tags. Not saying it shouldn't be made to go away also, but it's scale is... trickier.

Answer (score 13):

I also see absolutely no purpose to either of these tags. I would not complain to see them gone.

Answer (score -3):

I seen some user use the tag [port](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port), which could be more general to port binding or routing.

I don't see a problem to make remap all port-80, port-XX, etc... to simply [port](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/port)